# IMDB rating plugin not working with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, imdb

I have a page `movies.jsp` that is called through ajax from the page `home.jsp`. `movies.jsp` contains the code for the IMDB rating plugin ([link](http://www.imdb.com/plugins?titleId=tt1623205&ref_=tt_plg_rt)) :

```
<span class="imdbRatingPlugin" data-user="ur17960624" data-title="<%=request.getParameter("movieId") %>" data-style="p4">
    <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/<%=request.getParameter("movieId") %>/?ref_=plg_rt_1">
        <img src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/images/imdb_31x14.png" alt="Oz the Great and Powerful (2013) on IMDb" />
    </a>
</span>
<script>(function(d,s,id){var js,stags=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id)){return;}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js";stags.parentNode.insertBefore(js,stags);})(document,'script','imdb-rating-api');</script>
```

My ajax request is called like this :

```
$(document).on('click', 'imdb-button', function(){
    $('content').load('movies.jsp&movieId='+imdbmovieId');
});
```

The problem is that the request works fine the first time, but clicking on other movies with other movieIds returns just the IMDB logo and no rating. I suspect there's a problem with script in the plugin. I tried enclosing the script in a jquery function, and firing that function as a callback to the `load` everytime but that doesnt work. And ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was also tinkering with the plugin and can share some insight. If you are inserting IMDb ratings after the initial page-load then you need to call `rating.min.js` each time you add elements. You may also call `imdb.rating.createJSONP()` function which is maybe a better solution as there is no need to load the entire script again. You should know that the function iterates through all imdb `<span>` tags it finds.

IMDb rating plugin library is actually quite well explained and commented in this [version](http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.js).

Answer (score 1):

I got the issue resolved. The problem was that on every ajax request, it was creating the following script tag :

```
<script src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js" id="imdb-jsonp-tt12312312">
</script>
```

And multiple ajax meant multiple such tags, and some kind of confusion for the . I tried the following hack and it works :

```
$(document).on('click', 'imdb-button', function(){
    $('content').load('movies.jsp&movieId='+imdbmovieId', function(){
        imdbRatingTrigger();
    });
});

function imdbRatingTrigger(){
    $('[id^="imdb-jsonp"]').remove(); //to prevent creation of multiple script tags.

    (function(d,s,id){
        var js,stags=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id)){}js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/plugins/rating/js/rating.min.js";stags.parentNode.insertBefore(js,stags);
    })(document,'script','imdb-rating-api');
}
```

`$('[id^="imdb-jsonp"]').remove();` helps remove those duplicate script tags. Also I removed `return;` from the javascript function - `function(d,s,id()` which now forces the function to run completely everytime. I havent understood the complete science behind this hack, but it works.